# Javascript - Populating a form dynamically based on one object and filling in the values from another object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, forms, object

I have a JSON object that I use as a Template for all available Fields that can be added to an element in my Object that is used to Store the values.

I have another Object that holds values. The k,v of this Object storing all the values was not generated in my application. It is handed to me and I need to populate that value in a form that is created dynamically based on my JSON which defines all availabl keys for a given element. Its best I show you my demo app.

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/bGxFC/15/
1. Click "Button_2" label - Notice how it populates a form with 5 k,v inputs
2.Now click "Button_1" label - Notice how this has 6 k,v inputs
3. Both of these are "Type": "Button" but "Button_2" is missing 'Transition' from its inputs
4This is where my '`var controls`' object comes in. It defines all the available option that each type can have.
The Problem
I need to alter my code to use the values from '`objStr`' and place them into a form that was created by 'controls'. And once I add a value to an empty input(i.e.The 'Transition' input in "Button_2") it will be saved back to 'objStr'.

Here is my code:

```
     var controls = {
    "Button":{"Type": "", "Transition": "","BackgroundImage": "","Position": "","Width": "","Height": ""},

    "Image":{"Type": "","BackgroundImage": "","Position": "","Width": "","Height": ""},

    "Label":{"Type": "","Position": "","Width": "","Height": "","Text": "","FontSize":"","Color": "", "FontType": ""}
};


objStr = {
        "View_1":
        {
            "Image_1":{
                "Type":"Image",
                "BackgroundImage":"Image.gif",
                "Position":[0,0],
                "Width":320,
                "Height":480
            },
            "Button_1":{
                "Type":"Button",
                "BackgroundImage":"Button.gif",
                "Transition":"View2",
                "Position":[49,80],
                "Width":216,
                "Height":71
            },
            "Button_2":{
                "Type":"Button",
                "BackgroundImage":"Button2.gif",
                "Position":[65,217],
                "Width":188,
                "Height":134},
            "Label_1":{
                "Type":"Label",
                "Position":[106,91],
                "Width":96,
                "Height":34,
                "Text":"Button",
                "FontSize":32,
                "Color":[0.12549,0.298039,0.364706,1]
            }
        }
    };

$(document).ready(function () {
    var $objectList = $('<div id="main" />').appendTo($('#main'));
    $.each(objStr.View_1, function(k, v) {
        $('<div/>').append(k).appendTo($objectList).on('click', function(){
            var $wrapper = $('#form .wrapper').empty();
            if(typeof v === 'string') {
                $('<div class="item" />').append('<span class="key">' + k + '</span>' + '<input value="' + v + '"/>').appendTo($wrapper);
            }
            else {//object
                $('<h3 class="formHeading" />').append(k).appendTo($wrapper);
                $.each(v, function(key, val) {
                    $('<div class="item" />').append('<span class="key">' + key + '</span>' + '<input value="' + val + '"/>').appendTo($wrapper);
                });
            }
            $("<button>Save</button>").appendTo($wrapper).on('click', function() {
                if(typeof v === 'string') {
                    v = $(this).closest(".wrapper").find("input").val();
                }
                else {//object
                    $(this).closest(".wrapper").find(".item").each(function(i, div) {
                        var $div = $(div),
                            key = $div.find(".key").text(),
                            val = $div.find("input").val();
                        v[key] = val;
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```